# How do I get the weight from a Mettler-toledo PS60 scale via USB using PHP

Tags: php, usb

I see a lot of information on VB and ASP but nothing for PHP.

I want to get the weight from a Mettler-toledo PS60 scale. The scale is USB on a Windows computer. (possible a Mac too)

Just wondering if there is a way PHP can grab that information from the USB port?

If PHP can't be used how about Javascript or any other compatible language on a Linux server running PHP?

Comment: I wouldn't count on JavaScript being able to communicatie through USB.

Comment: Exactly how is PHP, running on your linux server, going to reach out through the interwebitubes to the Windows pc and access its usb stack?

Comment: You are right, This cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
<?php

$binary = fread(fopen('/dev/hidraw3', 'r'), 7);
$data = (object) unpack('Creport/Cstatus/Cunit/cexponent/vweight', $binary);
if ($data->report == 0x03 && $data->status == 0x04) 
{
    $data->weight = $data->weight * pow(10, $data->exponent);
    if ($data->unit == 0x0B) {
        // convert ounces to grams
        $data->weight *= 28.349523125;
        // and unit to grams
        $data->unit = 0x02;
    }

    if ($data->unit == 0x02) {
        echo "{$data->weight} g\n";
    } else {
        echo "{$data->weight} in other unit\n";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "error opening the serial port";
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't built a complete implementation yet, but I'm having success using [libusb](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/index.html) and this [phpmake_usb](https://github.com/oasynnoum/phpmake_usb) extension I found.